# Doing path & point plot using qplot()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

My data consists of three variables:volume, occ and state. I want to have a volume-occ path & point plot with the paths and points marked by different colours according to the state.
Here is my code:

```
qplot(occ,volume,data = data,geom=c('path','point'),color=factor(state))+scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue", "orange", "red"))
```

The outcome is like this:

[image: outcome1]

It seems that the qplot() does not connect the points in the initial order.Because the red points and paths are not connected with others, so are the other two coloured points.
I guess qplot() reordered my data according to the variable 'state', and then plot the path within each state separately.
I also tried the code without the colour arguement:

```
qplot(occ,volume,data = data,geom=c('path','point'))
```

The outcome is like this:

[image: outcome2]

This outcome does show the initial path order that I want.
What I want is every point being connected continuously in the initial order just like what outcome2 shows and marked by different colours according to the state variable.
What should I do with my code?

Comment: One advice for the next time you ask a question: add an reproducible example as described here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This will make things a lot easier for others to answer. This is also common practice among StackOverflow users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the color to a variable the data are also grouped by this variable. To prevent this set the group attribute manually to a constant. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:20, 
                 y = c(rnorm(10, 5, 2), rnorm(10, 5, 2)), 
                 group = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10) ))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = 1, col = group))+ geom_path()
```

The same with qplot:

```
qplot(x,y,data = df,geom=c('point'),color=factor(group), group = 1)
```

[image]

So just add `group = 1` to your code and it will work the way you expect it.